# Core Data with relationship one to many - Save/Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

The scenario is the following:

Each time the application starts it downloads a list of `Beacon`s (object) and a list of `Action`s (object). Each `Beacon` has zero or more action assigned. For the moment (and simplicity) each beacon has assigned one action.

So I am downloading the data and parsing the JSON into 2 `NSMutableArray`s. The `Beacon` object has some variables and the variable ID. The `Action` object has also some string variables and the relationship `beacon` which is the (foreign key) same as variable `id` in `Beacon`.

I have developed a singleton to save and load the data. At this point my code looks like these:

```
+(void)saveBeacons:(NSMutableArray*)array andAction(NSMutableArray*)actionsArray andManagedObject:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObject{

NSDictionary *jsonDict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObject;

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {        

    jsonDict3 = (NSDictionary*)[array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSManagedObject *newBeacon = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Beacon" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newBeacon setValue:[[jsonDict3 objectForKey:@"uuid"] uppercaseString] forKey:@"uuid"];
    [newBeacon setValue:[jsonDict3 objectForKey:@"minor"] forKey:@"minor"];
    [newBeacon setValue:[jsonDict3 objectForKey:@"major"] forKey:@"major"];        
}    

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Note: `array` contains the `Beacon` object and the `actionArray` the `Action`.

I know that I have to use nested loop but how I am supposed to add the relationship for each action with the beacon? Also I need to overwriting the data each time that the user is downloading the new data. Should I stop concidering to use Core Data?

PS. This is how my core data design looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering to your questions, few notes.

First, Why do you need to create an empty `NSDictionary`? And, what about if you are not using ARC? Make attention to memory leaks.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

In your for loop just do

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict3 = (NSDictionary*)[array objectAtIndex:i];
```

Second, I would rename the `id` identifier in your `Beacon` model as `beaconID` or something else. `id` is a keyword that means a pointer to a generic object. I would also rename `action` to `actions` just to highlight the one-to-many relationship between `Beacon` and `Action`.

Third, instead of using plain managed object you could use [`NSManagedObject` subclass](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-subclassing-nsmanagedobject--cms-21880).

Said this, about your questions.

> I know that I have to use nested loop but how I am supposed to add the relationship for each action with the beacon?

Inside the second `for loop` you need to create an action object and set its `beacon` relationship to the beacon (`newBeacon`) you created

```
[createdAction setValue:newBeacon forKey:@"beacon"];
```

Here you could have a problem, since you don't know if an action belongs to a beacon or to another one. You should find a method to filter the actions for a specific beacon. In this way, the save method could become:

```
+(BOOL)saveBeacon:(NSDictionary*)beaconRepresentation withActions:(NSArray*)actions {

    // Create a Beacon
    // For loop the array, create Actions and set the appropriate beacon relationships
    // Return the save result
}
```

> Also I need to overwriting the data each time that the user is downloading the new data.

It depends on what you need to achieve. What are your requirements?

> Should I stop concidering to use Core Data?

In this case Core Data provides you a well structured model layer. So, you can take advantage of it in order to fetch or save data, manage your object graph.